# I thought arrays are passed by value, so why can a method change the content of the original array

Tags: java, arrays

6. What will be output from the following code segment, assuming it is in the same class as the doSomething method?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
    System.out.println(arr[1]);
    doSomething(arr);
    System.out.println(arr[1]);
    System.out.println(arr[3]);
}
    
public static void doSomething(int[] list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i]=i;
    }
}
```

Answers:

```
A. 0 0
B. 2 4
C. 1 3
D. 0 2
E. 0 3
```

Correct Answer: C

I thought the correct answer would be B, since I thought the method could not affect the original array

Comment: `By those definitions, Java is always pass-by-value. Unfortunately, when we deal with variables holding objects we are really dealing with object-handles called references which are passed-by-value as well. This terminology and semantics easily confuse many beginners.`

 tl;dr Arrays are objects so the reference to the object is passed as a value.